# About analytic functions with nonnegative real part in the right-hand plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading some lecture notes where the following claim is made. Suppose $h(s)$ is analytic in the region $\{{\rm Re}(z) > 0 \}$, $h(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$,  and ${\rm Re}(h(iw)) \geq 0$ for all $w \in \mathbb{R}$. Then ${\rm Re}(h(s)) \geq 0$ whenever ${\rm Re}(s) > 0$.

If it helps, the claim is then applied to a rational $h(s)$, and I'd be happy to see a proof just for that case. In that case, analyticity just means the denominator has no roots in the right-half plane.

Comment: Is not $h(z) = z^3$ a counterexample?

Comment: It is, @cheapeffectivedietpills.

Comment: I guess $h(z)=-z$ is a simpler one.

Comment: Thank you, @cheapeffectivedietpills. That is indeed a counterexample. 

Could it be that the claim is true if ${\rm Re}(h(iw)) > 0$ instead?

Comment: No. Just add $1$ to the preceding counterexamples.

Comment: mmm, right. Thank you!